# How to load iframe in IE8 within the parent html page which loads in IE Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode

We have a webpage with IE Edge compatibility

within which we have an iframe that must run in IE8 compatibility mode

How to achieve this...

Comment: You can't, the ability was removed since IE9, if I can recall it correctly.